# Can't install WolframScript

Tags: free-wolfram-engine

I tried install WolframScript to use WolframLanguage in Jupyter notebook.
https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

Wolfram Language kernel for Jupyter notebooks requires WolframEngine and WolframScript. WolframEngine was correctly installed. I could logged in with my wolfram ID and calculate something in Terminal.app.
However, WolframScript doesn't work. It says,

```
The product exited during an activation attempt because an error occurred.

[Process completed]
```

This may also cause the error below when I run `./configure-jupyter.wls add` in WolframLanguageForJupyter directory

```
sh: /WolframKernel: No such file or directory
```

It can execute only numerical calculation in Terminal and can't plot the answer. I would like to use Jupyter notebook to work Plot[].

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE! For this sort of problem, you’ll likely have better luck with this on [Community](https://community.wolfram.com).

Answer (score 6):

I was in trouble with my MBP too but I finally solved this problem.

Please check this site:
https://support.wolfram.com/47243

and read the section "How do I specify which kernel WolframScript should use?".

Next please launch WolframScript from the command line with the command as written.

You will see the message  "Configured:WOLFRAMSCRIPT_KERNELPATH=/Applications/Wolfram Engine.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel" if your machine is Mac (just example).

Now you can use "wolframscript" command.

The problem was so simple I think. Only WolframEngine(kernel) asks activation, so only it knows about it. However, WolframScript needs activation too, but there is only one-time activation to avoid asking many  times.
Then we need to tell wolframscript where the kernel is of course.